# Weighted Average Calculations across various combinations using Cube.js

Tags: cube.js

We have a question on designing schema and handling analytics requirement for our product and would appreciate your advise on this. We are just getting started with  Cube.js. Here is our req: We have data (for simplicity...i will use an example) where say we have multiple columns (attributes) and say 1 "value" and 1 "weight" column. We need to calculate weighted averages across all combinations of the columns (attributes) and the value / weight columns.
e.g. Group by Column 1 and weighted average (value/Weight column)
or Group by Column 1, 2 and weighted average etc. etc...
it can be many types of combinations and we have atleast 8 to 12 columns like that
Wondering how best to model?

Answer (score 0):

Probably for you will be convenient to create one cube with several predefined [segments](https://cube.dev/docs/segments) or also you can create several cubes per each attribute.

It depends on your data.